# Return words with double consecutive letters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to make a python program to return the words that have double consecutive letters, (e.g., door, ball, floor).  My code until now is this the following, but it returns me all the words in the files divided in two-letter parts:

```
def text_processing( file_location ):
    import re
    file_variable = open( file_location )
    lines = file_variable.read()
    print lines

    double_letter = re.compile('[A-Z]{2,2}', re.IGNORECASE)
    double_letter_list = double_letter.findall(lines)

    print double_letter_list
```

Comment: You can use `{2}` instead of `{2,2}` (though that doesn't fix the issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
def text_processing( file_location ):
    import re
    file_variable = open( file_location )
    lines = file_variable.readlines()

    double_letter = re.compile(r'.*(.)\1.*', re.IGNORECASE)
    double_letter_list = []

    for line in lines:
        for word in line.split(" "):
            match = double_letter.match(word)
            if match:
                double_letter_list.append(match.group())

    print double_letter_list
```

It tries to match the pattern against each word in the file, and if it is a match it appends it to the list of double words.

Answer (score 6):

Try this regex: `r"\w*(\w)\1\w*"`

Answer (score 2):

```
re.findall('(\w*(\w)\\2\w*)', file_variable.read())
```

Will return a list of tuples *(word, repeated letter)*, you can then just take all of the first elements.

Example:

```
>>> re.findall('(\w*(\w)\\2\w*)', 'some words here: boo, shoo, wooooo, etc.')
[('boo', 'o'), ('shoo', 'o'), ('wooooo', 'o')]
```

Comment: (.) should be (\w) or this will also capture two words separated by two identical characters, like spaces.