# python: how to find consecutive pairs of letters by regex?

Tags: python, regex

I want to find words that have consecutive letter pairs using regex.
I know for just one consecutive pair like **zoo (oo), puzzle (zz), arrange (rr)**, it can be achieved by `'(\w){2}'`. But how about

- two consecutive pairs:   **committee (ttee)**
- three consecutive pairs:   **bookkeeper (ookkee)**

edit:

- `'(\w){2}'` is actually wrong, it finds any two letters instead of a double letter pair.
- My intention is to find the **words** that have letter pairs, not the pairs.
- By 'consecutive', I mean there is no other letter between letter pairs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return words with double consecutive letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593622/return-words-with-double-consecutive-letters)

Comment: `\w{2}` only refers to two letters, 'ab', 'cc' are both OK.

Comment: actually, '(\w){2}' matches any 2 consecutive letters, matching or not. It will match 'zo' on 'zoo'.

Comment: @zhangyangyu   You guys are right, thanks for correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
[a-z]*([a-z])\1([a-z])\2[a-z]*
```

the idea is to use backreferences `\1` and `\2` that refer to the capturing groups.

Note that `(\w){2}` matches two word characters but not the same character.

Comment: It works! So to find words of three consecutive letter pairs, the regex would be `[a-z]*([a-z])\1([a-z])\2[a-z]*([a-z])\3[a-z]*`, but it not only finds **bookkeeper** but also **greenness**, which breaks the 'consecutive' rule. How to avoid this?

Comment: @Teacode: no for three you must write: `[a-z]*([a-z])\1([a-z])\2([a-z])\3[a-z]*`

Comment: You are right! Thank you. Feel shame for my mistake, I am a total beginner with regex.

Comment: @Teacode: Note that you can easily adapt falsetru solution to what you want: `[a-z]*(([a-z])\2)+[a-z]*`

Comment: This does also find words with 4 consecutive letters, e.g. "heeeelp" would match (even though it's not a real word). Any idea on how to prevent that? I tried `([a-z])\1([^\1])\2` but the regex engine i was using said it is invalid

Comment: @Luke: you can't use a backreference inside a character class since `\n` (where n is capture group number) looses it's special meaning inside it. If you want to exclude words with more than two consecutive same letter, you can use a negative lookbehind: `\b(?![a-z]*([a-z])\1{4})[a-z]*([a-z])\2([a-z])\3[a-z]*`

Comment: I guess it makes sense when you realise a backreference could actually evaluate to a sequence of more than one character, so it doesn't make sense in a character class

Comment: Good answer. It would have helped me to explain that "([a-z])\1" matches 2 letters. Then explain the douple two letters, otherwise I didn't understand the whole thing right away.

Answer (score 15):

Use [re.finditer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer)

```
>>> [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'((\w)\2)+', 'zoo')]
['oo']
>>> [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'((\w)\2)+', 'arrange')]
['rr']
>>> [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'((\w)\2)+', 'committee')]
['mm', 'ttee']
>>> [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'((\w)\2)+', 'bookkeeper')]
['ookkee']
```

Check whether the string contain consecutive pair:

```
>>> bool(re.search(r'((\w)\2){2}', 'zoo'))
False
>>> bool(re.search(r'((\w)\2){2}', 'arrange'))
False
>>> bool(re.search(r'((\w)\2){2}', 'committee'))
True
>>> bool(re.search(r'((\w)\2){2}', 'bookkeeper'))
True
```

You can also use following non-capturing (`?:`) version:

```
(?:(\w)\1){2}
```

Comment: I guess my question was badly formed. Instead of finding the letter pairs from a word, what I really want to do is to find the words(from a word list) that have consecutive letter pairs.

Comment: Thank you. Now I got it. `((\w)\2){3}` is equivalent to `(\w)\1(\w)\2(\w)\3`, and more elegant!

Comment: You can make the outer set of parentheses non-capturing, if you want (which seems a bit cleaner to me): `(?:(\w)\1)`

Comment: @Blckknght, Thank you for comment. I edited the answer to mention your non-capturing version.

Answer (score 1):

For detecting **2-or-more consecutive letters** the regex becomes: `(\w)\1+`

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned that you want to test from a list, I have answered as such. Using falsetru's answer:

```
newlist = []

for word in list:
  if [m.group() for m in re.finditer(r'((\w)\2)+', word)] != []:
     newlist.append(word)

print newlist
```